# slow work with ob_get_content()

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, buffer

i have a problem with work speed my code.
I have this code

```
$res_include = requireToVar('parts/keywords_table.php', $array_vars);
```

and my custom function

```
function requireToVar($file, $array = null)
{
    ob_start();
    extract($array);
    include "$file";
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

i need generate an html with data and back into page via ajax response.
So, in html file i generate 2000 lines of table.
and put this code in variable.

this code work at 10-15 seconds and this very slow.

Please give me a tip or some ideas how i can optimize this code.
This is included file

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <th>№</th>
    <th>Ключевое слово</th>
    <th>Search volume</th>
    <th>Av. CPC</th>
    <th>competitions</th>
    <th>Статистика за год</th>
    <th>Source</th>
    <!--<th>categories</th>-->
    <?php $i = 1;foreach ($res as $keyword) :?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i++ ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $keyword->keyword ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $keyword->search_volume ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $keyword->average_CPC ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $keyword->competition ?></td>
            <?php if(is_array($keyword->year_stats)) :?>
                <td>
                    <div class="year_stats">
                        <a class="year_stats_btn btn btn-info">Статистика за год</a>
                        <ul class="year_stats_list list-group">
                            <?php foreach ($keyword->year_stats as $stat) :?>
                                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Year - <?php echo $stat->year ?>; month - <?php echo $stat->month ?>; count - <?php echo $stat->count ?>;</li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            <?php else: ?>
                <td>
                   &mdash;
                </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td><b><?php echo $keyword->source ?></b></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php if(isset($searched_also) && !empty($searched_also)) :?>
    <h2>Поисковые запросы, которые также делали потребители (Yandex)</h2>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <th>№</th>
        <th>Ключевое слово</th>
        <th>Search volume</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <?php $i = 1;foreach ($searched_also as $also_item) :?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i++ ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $also_item->keyword ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $also_item->search_volume ?></td>
                <td><b><?php echo $also_item->source ?></b></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem sometime ago the server was writing too much html and load times were slooow.

What i did when i didn't know the existence of Ajax was to send all the data as a JSON and use datatables as u can see in this [forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32107/how-to-load-an-array-of-json-objects-to-datatables), this way is quite simple if u don't want or can't use ajax with datatables.

Other posibility is to load data on ur table using Ajax, also an example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html), all i did was to call a query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 10 OFFSET $value;
```

the offset value u can set it with some pagination on ur table, lets say u want to show 10 records, so if u go to page 2 the offset would be 10.

Hope my answer helps u.